# scrollbar for div

Tags: jquery

Can someone provide me with information on how to add both vertical and horizontal scrollbar using jquery? For example a textbox with an Id="txtBox".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CSS

```
#txtBox {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Adding the CSS property with JQuery:

```
$("#txtBox").css("overflow", "scroll");
```

You could also use ***overflow-x*** and ***overflow-y*** separately.